# Angular - Cannot store json data in variable with .subsribe

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm facing a problem where I can not store the data what I'm getting in a variable when doing a Post request...  How can I store the specific data that I want in a variable?

I did a Post request where I'm getting data back, but it simply does not store the data that I want in the variable.

My Code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslatedText } from './TranslatedText';
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
import { resource } from 'selenium-webdriver/http';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})


export class TranslateService {


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


  getTranslation(textToTranslate: string): Observable<TranslatedText> {


    const options = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } };
    let body = JSON.stringify({ Text: textToTranslate });
    console.log("json ", body);



    let result = this.http.post<TranslatedText>('https://localhost:5001/api/translate/', body, options);
    console.log("result", result);
    return result




  }
}
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '../translate.service';
import { TranslatedText, Translations } from '../TranslatedText';
import { THIS_EXPR } from '@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast';
import { TmplAstText } from '@angular/compiler';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-translate',
  templateUrl: './translate.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./translate.component.css']
})

export class TranslateComponent implements OnInit {

  tText: Object[];


  constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  textTranslation = "This text is about to get translated";



  text3: TranslatedText = new TranslatedText();



  getTranslation(textToTranslate: string) {

     this.translateService.getTranslation(textToTranslate).subscribe(
      data => {
       this.text3.translations = data.translations;
        console.log('Data that I get',data)
      });

      console.log(this.text3);


  }

}
```

json what i'm getting back:

```
[
    {
        "detectedLanguage": {
            "language": "en",
            "score": 1
        },
        "translations": [
            {
                "text": "Hallo Welt!",
                "to": "de"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

```
export class TranslatedText {
    detectedLanguage: DetectedLanguage;
    translations: Translations[];
}

export class DetectedLanguage {
    language: string;
    score: number;
}
export class Translations {

    text: string;
    to: string;

}
```

```
<p>
  translate works!
</p>

<label>Translate</label>
<input #text type="text" value="{{textTranslation}}"> <br>

<!-- <div *ngIf="text3">
  <h1>{{text2}}</h1>
</div> -->

<div *ngIf="text3.translations[0].text.length">
{{text3.translations[0].text}}
</div>


<button (click)="getTranslation(text.value)">TRANSLATE (gives Json back) </button>
```

I expected to store in this.text3.translations  the values of data.translations, but it says that data.translations is undefined. I debugged and looked if it had values and it had.

https://gyazo.com/1bf9f7f3d9fe491a479d1d837f32428a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try by formatting the code below, in second ts of your question to

```
getTranslation(textToTranslate: string) {

     this.translateService.getTranslation(textToTranslate).subscribe(
          data => {
           this.text3.translations = data.translations;
            console.log('Data that I get',data)

            console.log(this.text3); // <--- check this value
          });
  }
```

Also could you change below code in service from

```
let result = this.http.post<TranslatedText>('https://localhost:5001/api/translate/', body, options);
    console.log("result", result);
    return result
```

to

```
return this.http.post<TranslatedText>('https://localhost:5001/api/translate/', body, options);
```

To display the value you can do this

```
<div *ngIf="text3 && text3.translations && text3.translations[0].text.length">
 {{text3.translations[0].text}}
</div>
```

or

```
<div *ngIf="text3?.translations[0]?.text?.length">
 {{text3.translations[0].text}}
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I'm getting this https://gyazo.com/d8ce0abef33d4fd0a58d3be106044fc3

Comment: This one is more clear: https://gyazo.com/13430a66483d37ead2e7af252cd14507

Comment: Legend, can you help me with 1 more problem. I want to display the changed value in the html. I'll put the html code in it aswell

Comment: Also why did it not work before? I literally returned result?

Comment: It didn't work first because when you return the variable its actually returning the variables value at that time, which is undefined since its an asynchronous call it will take time to get the result back and get assigned. So always return the call itself. Hope you understood what I meant

Comment: Thank you very much @Seba Cherian